# Unable to access supervisord web interface in aws server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, supervisord

I am using supervisord tool in AWS server to do run some scripts automatically.I am able to see the status of the process in AWS server directly by executing below commands in command line.

```
supervisorctl>status
```

But i wanna see the process status in WebGui so that i configured below settings in supervisord.conf file.

```
[inet_http_server]
port=*:9001
user = dummy
[supervisorctl]
[unix_http_server]
file = /tmp/supervisor.sock
chmod=0700
```

Url:55.121.35.22:9001

But the problem is I am unable to see in the browser and it is showing the below error message.

This site can’t be reached

55.121.35.22 took too long to respond.

Answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check that the service is indeed listening on all interfaces:

```
netstat -anp | egrep '9001.*LISTEN'
```

You can then test the app by using `wget` or `curl` locally:

```
wget http://127.0.01:9001
```

If both of those tests pass, I would then check your security groups on the AWS instance and make sure that TCP port 9001 is allowed. If it's not allowed, you should allow it, but only for a whitelisted IP address or IP range.

Comment: In AWS server i am able to access supervisord page by executing **wget http://127.0.01:9001** . But in my local system it is showing connection refused, though I added port in firewall settings.
localhost refused to connect.